# Virtual application solution for Linux Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In a Windows Azure Web App we are able to set up a virtual application in which we could push separate code in . Is there any solution similar to this for a Linux Azure Web App?

Comment: elaborate your question. if you add more information it would be helpful to address the issue accurately.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a feature in IIS, that is why it doesn't work in linux. There's no out of the box support for this feature on Azure web app for Linux / containers. you need to implement it by youyself.