# Alternative to Virtual applications and directories for Linux container

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My team wants to deploy an Azure App Service that's running a React frontend and a Python Flask backend in a Linux environment.  I've seen a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607577/virtual-application-solution-for-linux-web-app) stating that virtual applications and directories are unavailable for Linux.  I [heard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810572/node-application-on-azure-web-app-virtual-directory-is-not-shown) that using custom storage is an alternative approach to allowing multiple applications to run on the same App Service.

If it's not a viable alternative, then what would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, virtual application is **not supported** for Linux environment on Azure.

Here is some supported links:

1. Virtual directory is IIS concept basically. [we can't create virtual directory for Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212842/is-it-possible-to-create-a-virtual-directory-in-linux).
2. For [Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#windows-apps-uncontainerized), you can customize the IIS handler mappings and virtual applications and directories.
3. Just like [Joey Cai said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810572/node-application-on-azure-web-app-virtual-directory-is-not-shown), you could use container to proxy multiple applications on Linux, but virtual application is unreachable, because the port would be occupied for the default application.
4. [Running multiple sites in a single Linux web app was not officially supported.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/82133/is-it-possible-to-deploy-multiple-web-applications.html#)

Comment: Only the front end really needs to be exposed.  We don't want people to make calls directly against the backend

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405337/azure-web-app-route-different-external-domains-to-different-directories-in-si/65406771#65406771)

TL;DR: Instead of relying on virtual directories, you can host each of your application on its own, dedicated App Service. To save costs, multiple App Services can share the same App Service Plan (the underlying compute)